# How to query all metrics of a specific pod using prometheusQL

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm trying to query all prometheus metrics of a pod that I have but I got an error.

Query:
`curl -s GET 'http://127.0.0.1:9090/api/v1/query?query={kubernetes_pod_name="my-app"}'`

Error:
`{"status":"error","errorType":"bad_data","error":"invalid parameter \"query\": 1:20: parse error: unexpected \"=\""}`

Any hints on how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Add the parameter "--globoff" to the "curl" command:

```
curl -s --globoff GET 'http://127.0.0.1:9090/api/v1/query?query={kubernetes_pod_name="my-app"}'
```